# How to find defects injected user (person who violated quality gate condition) in SonarQube

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube

I have configured SonarQube with quality gate metrics with Code smell, Vulnerabilities, Bugs, Code coverage and etc.

When someone committed the code to git, I want to find who violates the quality gate condition, I mean who injected a buggy code to the git.

In jenkis I can get the last commit user, but that is not practical always because if there are 2 users and first user commits with bugs and second user commit again with quality code and push it to the git. Then the second user is not the person who responsible for violating the quality gate condition.

I tried generating CNES report as described in here.
https://github.com/cnescatlab/sonar-cnes-report

This works fine. But in my case because of the version miss matches and other unavoidable dependencies this method is not applicable for me.

I am asking this question to know is there any other methods to get the commit user who violated the quality gate condition. I tried to find any other working method, but I couldn't up to now.

If someone with similar experience, please answer to this. Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: I'm not sure how Sonar Cube exactly works, but usually if you'd like to find out who modified some particular file, then you could use `git blame` command https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame

Comment: To find which commit introduced some particular problem that can't be observed as simply as inspecting a source file, `git bisect` is usually the right tool. So either blame/annotate (same command), or bisect.